# Sequelize migration error in nodejs with postgreSQL and express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, migration, sequelize.js

first, I created a wrong migration so delete a migration file.but when i try to run new migration it show the error of old migration as error: "Error in running migrations column \"is_ac\" of relation \"users\" already exists
i am using sequelize with node js and postgreSql.
is_ac migration file already deleted.

Comment: yes i am using bitbucket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
thanks to all .issue was in my azure pipeline.i was not deleting old migration from zip.the new code is ....
"use strict";
const tableName = "jobs";
const columnName = "job_deposit_taken";

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    const columnType = Sequelize.JSONB;
    return queryInterface.describeTable(tableName).then(tableDefinition => {
      if (!tableDefinition[columnName]) {
        return queryInterface.addColumn(tableName, columnName, columnType);
      } else {
        return Promise.resolve();
      }
    });
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.removeColumn(tableName, columnName);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete "is_ac migration" migration file from the database table "SequelizeMeta".
See if that works.

Comment: i have truncate SequelizeMeta table when i run project it runs 5 migration after is shows same error